# USB devices not properly powered off/disconnected when computer shuts down

Tags: usb

Ubuntu 17.10 (GNOME)

I have some problems with my WiFi USB adapter. It works, but every time I reboot (or just shut it down and power it back on) my PC, I have to replug it. At first I thought it was a problem with the drivers, but then I realized it also works when I shut the computer down, replug the adapter and power it back on. Also, my mouse has RGB lights that still light up after shutting my computer down, suggesting there's something wrong with disconnecting the USB devices when shutting down or something like that.

Any help is much appreciated. I *think* I'm describing everything clearly enough, but if you need more info (hardware, more detailed description of the problem, etc.), just tell me.

-Sam

UPDATE: @N0rbert's suggestion fixed it for me. Thanks a lot for the help, everybody! :)

If you have this problem too: for Gigabyte motherboards it's in the BIOS, under power management. There should be an option called ErP (sometimes EuP), just enable it and it should work. For other motherboards it should be something similar. Just a warning: options like power on by mouse/keyboard and wake on LAN won't work if you enable this setting.

I'm not sure how I can close a thread without having an actual "answer". I added "(solved)" to the title, but if someone could close this thread or tell me how to do it, that would be nice (helps people who have the same problem).

Comment: how do you shut down? are you sure that you aren't suspending?

Comment: Include output of `acpitool -w`.

Comment: It may be ACPI problem, or wrong settings in BIOS. Some computers and laptops has always on USB for charging mobile devices. Check this.

Comment: @ravery I usually shut down using the top-right "power off" menu. I tried doing `sudo shutdown now`, but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Legolas [Here](https://pastebin.com/2xZ3uPUe) is the output of `acpitool -w`.

Comment: @N0rbert Yeah, that could be it. I'll see if I can find an option for that in the BIOS.

Comment: @N0rbert Yep, that was it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I converted my comment to [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/978463/66509). You can vote for it and mark it as accepted solution :)

Comment: Ok, I voted for your answer and marked it as accepted. (Although it doesn't show my vote because I have less than 15 reputation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be ACPI problem, or wrong settings in BIOS. Some computers and laptops has always on USB for charging mobile devices. Check this.